# Specify the CLR .NET Framework version in native C++

Tags: c++, .net, clr

In a native C++ program I load a CLR and start it using a ICLRRuntimeHost interface. Before I load any .NET assemblies I'd like to specify the Framework version the CLR will use.

I believe it uses the one associated with the first assembly you load by default. I've found that if you first load an assembly that uses 4.0, a later attempt to load one that uses 4.5 will fail.

I'd like to load the CLR and specify 4.5 before loading the first assembly so that they'll both load, regardless of the order.

Comment: I think you can specify TargetFrameworkVersion https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx

Comment: I may be mistaken but it appears the msdn article you referenced deals with the development environment; I'm interested in specifying the version at runtime.